# createPeerAdminCard.sh not taking full path

Tags: node.js, windows, cygwin, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I was trying to create PeerAdminCard in hyperledger but it was not inlcuding my whole username path like my windows username is "Ned Stark" then while running createPeerAdminCard.sh it was online fecthing "Ned" not whole name on cygwin on windows 10 pro please help even i have tried changin username then it showing error composer-cli not found and even after installing composer cli it shows same not found

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Hyperledger Composer doesn't support windows, so you can't use it in Git Bash, Command Window,  Powershell or Windows Subsystem for Linux. If you want to continue to use composer (and given that it looks like you are starting out, you should not consider hyperledger composer but look straight to using hyperledger fabric as hyperledger composer has been deprecated) then you either have to use a Mac or use a hypervisor (such as VMware, Virtualbox or hyper-v) and run Ubuntu Linux 16.04 desktop.